# property of poisson process

Tags: probability, poisson-process

I am reading a probability book and I have the following question about the poisson process. Let $N(t), t\ge 0$ be a poisson process with parameter $\lambda$. Then we know that $N(t+s)-N(t)$ does not depend on $t$. Let $s=t$, we get
$$N(2t)-N(t)=N(t)-N(0)=N(t).  $$
Then we see that the two random variables $N(2t)$ and $2N(t)$ are the same. 
But obviously,  for a general $k$, 
$$P(N(2t)=k)\ne  P(N(t)=k/2). $$
Can somebody point out  to me my  misunderstanding?

Comment: The two sides in your first equation are equal in terms of distribution. The number of ocurrences in $[t,2t)$ and  $[0,t)$ have the same distribution but they do not need to be the same.

Answer (score 2):

It is not at all correct to say that $N(2t)-N(t)=N(t)-N(0)=N(t).$

Rather, it is **the probability distributions of** $N(2t)-N(t)$ and $N(t)-N(0)$ that are equal.

Nor is $N(2t)$ the same as $2N(t),$ and in that case even the probability distributions are not equal, although the expected values are. Every value of $2N(t)$ is an even integer, and that is not true of $N(2t).$